# ASMifier doesn't display enough

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to use ASMifier to understand exactly what is in my .class files. The problem is that the tool omits certain mv.visitXXX. For instance, it doesn't display mv.visitLabel(Label) for line-declaring labels.

It makes sense because ASMifier displays only the mv.visit needed to create the class but I would like to use it in a different way.

Is there anyway to ask the tool to display everything that it visits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conditional treatment in `ASMifier` for labels associated with source code lines, in other words, if the `ClassReader` reports them, `ASMifier` will show them.

For this to work, two conditions must be met:

1. The method must have a `LineNumberTable` attribute associated with its `Code` attribute (for ordinary classes, this is driven by the compiler options used when generating the `.class` file).
2. You must not have specified `SKIP_DEBUG` to the `accept` method of the `ClassReader`

When using `javac`, the presence or absence of debug information is controlled by the `-g` option. The default is to generate `LineNumberTable` attributes, so not specifying the `-g` option is already sufficient. So the following program

```
package bytecodetests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor;

public class BytecodeTests {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new ClassReader(BytecodeTests.class.getResourceAsStream("BytecodeTests.class"))
      .accept(new TraceClassVisitor(null, new ASMifier(), new PrintWriter(System.out)), 0);
  }

}
```

will produce

```
package asm.bytecodetests;
import java.util.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.*;
public class BytecodeTestsDump implements Opcodes {

public static byte[] dump () throws Exception {

ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
FieldVisitor fv;
MethodVisitor mv;
AnnotationVisitor av0;

cw.visit(52, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, "bytecodetests/BytecodeTests", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

cw.visitSource("BytecodeTests.java", null);

{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(9, l0);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V", false);
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "Lbytecodetests/BytecodeTests;", null, l0, l1, 0);
mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
mv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, new String[] { "java/io/IOException" });
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(12, l0);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getType("Lbytecodetests/BytecodeTests;"));
mv.visitLdcInsn("BytecodeTests.class");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Class", "getResourceAsStream", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader", "<init>", "(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V", false);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitInsn(ACONST_NULL);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier", "<init>", "()V", false);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/io/PrintWriter");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/io/PrintWriter", "<init>", "(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor", "<init>", "(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;Lorg/objectweb/asm/util/Printer;Ljava/io/PrintWriter;)V", false);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLineNumber(13, l1);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader", "accept", "(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;I)V", false);
Label l2 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l2);
mv.visitLineNumber(14, l2);
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
Label l3 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l3);
mv.visitLocalVariable("args", "[Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l3, 0);
mv.visitMaxs(8, 1);
mv.visitEnd();
}
cw.visitEnd();

return cw.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Note the presence of the

```
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(12, l0);
…
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLineNumber(13, l1);
…
Label l2 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l2);
mv.visitLineNumber(14, l2);
…
```

calls for the `main` method.

---

When running `ASMifier` from command line, it does indeed default to using the `SKIP_DEBUG` flag unless the `-debug` option has been given as first argument.

Comment: Thanks I was using the ASMifier tool by command line : java -cp "asm-all-5.1.jar" org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier Foo.class > Foo.asm  but your solution is perfect for my needs.